# dvc (data version control) error - ImportError: cannot import name 'fsspec_loop' from 'fsspec.asyn'

Tags: dvc, fsspec

I use Python version 3.7.13 and create a virtual environment (venv) for a MLOps project.

A dvc package (=2.10.2) that is compatible with Python== 3.7.13 is installed in this venv.

```
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % dvc --version
2.10.2
```

But when running the dvc initiation:

```
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % dvc init
```

An import error as follows occurs:

```
from fsspec.asyn import fsspec_loop
ImportError: cannot import name 'fsspec_loop' from 'fsspec.asyn'
```

I try the following:

1. Go to the file location /venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py and inspect the file asyn.py. Find that there is no function with the name "fsspec_loop".
2. Try to upgrade the dvc to a newer version by,

```
pip install dvc --upgrade
```

But the dvc version remains the same (2.10.2).

3. Uninstall dvc by,

```
pip uninstall dvc
```

and try to install the newest version,

```
pip install dvc==2.42.0
```

The response shows that the latest version of dvc that is compatible with Python 3.7.13 is 2.10.2. As a result, version 2.42.0 cannot be installed.

4. Try to install dvc using brew. But the dvc is installed in a location outside the venv (at /usr/local/bin, where a later version of Python is used).

```
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % brew install dvc
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % dvc --version
2.41.1
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % which dvc
/usr/local/bin/dvc
```

The entire traceback (most recent call last) is as follows,

[image: traceback]

Comment: last fsspec version deleted fsspec_loop and newer adlfs version has that handled as well. Please check that `pip check` doesn't point out any errors and try downgrading fsspec version to 2022.11.0.

Also note that 3.7 support was dropped last year, and dvc supports 3.8+.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @ruslankuprieiev.

dvc version 2.10.2 is successfully installed and initialized in the venv with Python 3.7.13 after downgrading fsspec to version 2022.11.0 .

The following are the steps.

1. Install dvc version 2.10.2,
2. Check which dvc is used (the one in venv),
3. Check fsspec version number (== 2023.1.0),
4. Force reinstall to downgrade fsspec to 2022.11.0,
5. Check fsspec version number again (== 2022.11.0), and
6. Force initialize dvc since there is an existing .dvc folder in the project directory.

The code is as follows,

```
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % pip install dvc==2.10.2
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % which dvc
/PathtoFile/venv/bin/dvc
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % pip show fsspec
Name: fsspec
Version: 2023.1.0
...
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % pip install --force-reinstall -v "fsspec==2022.11.0"
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % pip show fsspec
Name: fsspec
Version: 2022.11.0
...
(venv) (base) tony3@Tonys-MacBook-Pro mlops % dvc init -f
```

Comment: i would suggest upgrading to python 3.8+ too, 3.7 will reach EOL this summer, a lot of tools are dropping it already. Also dvc 2.10.2 is very old, so you are missing out on some fixes and optimizations in the latest versions.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem and solved it by installing an older version "fsspec". (my python is 3.8 and dvc 2.8.3)

```
pip uninstall fsspec
pip install fsspec==2022.7.1
```

Comment: I did the same with mamba (I installed dvc with mamba). So the whole installation process for me was as follows

`conda install -c conda-forge mamba` `mamba install -c conda-forge dvc` `mamba install -c conda-forge fsspec==2022.7.1`
My python is 3.7.4 and I have Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Actually, as of today Feb 20 2023, support is only available from Python 3.8+ (from the docs), and indeed, with this installation I cannot `dvc push` to Google Drive. So I just created a new env with Python 3.8 and now it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the below conda command, this worked like charm for me.

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge fsspec
```